# Jagged Array to 2D Array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, range, jagged-arrays

i had created a jagged array of non-contigeous columns from a range (excluding any blank or zero-filled columns). now i want to join the different columns in the jagged array and convert it to a 2-Dimensional array that we get if we pass a range to a variant. i am unable to pull the column names using INDEX or TRANSPOSE to populate XValues, Values and Series.Name of a 100%StackedBarChart, hence the need.

here are the screenshots:

### JAGGED ARRAY:

[image]

### RANGE ARRAY:

[image]

as you can see in the jagged array, each column cells are shown outermost and row cells 1 to 5 are shown innermost, whereas in range 2d-array, it is viceversa. the columns and rows are of same size viz., 5 rows and 2 columns.

how do i convert back the jagged array to a normal range type rectangular 2D-array? Can anyone help me quickly?
Thanks.

Comment: The only way I know is to create a 2D-array and fill it with a for loop.

Comment: how do i setup such a 2D array? can you give me an example?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

On Florent's idea, i actually wrote my own Jagged2Rectconverter:

```
   Dim tarr
   ReDim tarr(1 To UBound(TempArr(1), 1), 1 To UBound(TempArr, 1))

   For c = LBound(TempArr, 1) To UBound(TempArr, 1)
       For r = LBound(TempArr(c), 1) To UBound(TempArr(c), 1)
           tarr(r, c) = TempArr(c)(r, 1)
       Next r
   Next c
```

now tarr() gives me the same Rect array:

[image]

any quicker way of doing this without looping? :)

Comment: You won't find anything quicker since it's the only way. However you could improve this one by declaring tarr() As Variant, c as Long, r as long and by using variables for the bounds in the second for.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a good result with transposing the jagged array,
then jagged (1,1)=1

From there on I could manipulate( slice) the array.

Without transpose jagged(1)(1,1)=1

Comment: Transpose won't work if array is large.

Comment: Absolutely, after 65536 the array gets truncated without warning.